# CSS: how to set first grid row to fixed height and then distribute height for dynamic number of grid rows following that

Tags: css

I'm using grid.  I have my first row as 20px and I want all subsequent rows to use `1fr` to distribute the height evenly.  I am doing `grid-template-rows: 20px repeat(2, 1fr);` but that only applies to my set number of divs in my code.  I want it to work for a dynamic number of divs.  I tried `grid-template-rows: 20px repeat(auto-fill, 1fr);` but that just set them all evenly (even the first one).

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 20px;
  grid-template-columns: 20px 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 20px repeat(2, 1fr);
  background: green;
  height: 100%;
}

.container div {
  background: grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div>11</div>
    <div>22</div>
    <div>33</div>
    <div>44</div>
    <div>55</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `grid-auto-rows`

```css
body {
  margin:0;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 20px;
  grid-template-columns: 20px 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 20px; /* first one 20px */
  grid-auto-rows:1fr; /* all the others 1fr */
  background: green;
  height: 100vh;
}

.container div {
  background: grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div>11</div>
    <div>22</div>
    <div>33</div>
    <div>44</div>
    <div>55</div>
    <div>66</div>
    <div>77</div>
</div>
```